# GSON - Get JSON value from String

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I'm trying to parse the JSON String "{'test': '100.00'}" and in order to get the value: `100.00` with the GSON library. My code looks like this:

```
String myJSONString = "{'test': '100.00'}";
JsonObject jobj = new Gson().fromJson(myJSONString, JsonObject.class);

String result = jobj.get("test").toString();

System.out.println(result);
```

My result looks like this: `"100.00"`, but I would need just `100.00` without the quotes. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

```
double result = jobj.get("test").getAsDouble();
```

Comment: This would throw a NPE if the entry "test" does not exists

Answer (score 20):

Try

```
String result = jobj.get("test").getAsString();
```

get(String) method returns [JsonElement](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html) object which you then should get the value from.

Comment: getAsString() intentionally throws an UnsupportedOperationException

Answer (score 1):

```
double getDoubleFromString = Double.parseDouble(result);
```

EDIT: 
per the comment below: Here is some explanation

if you ever have a string => in this case "result" was set to a string on line 3. The key "test" in the myJSONString variable has a value of 100.00 In order to "DOUBLEFY" this value of 100.00, you call the parseDouble method from the Double class. Thats is how to convert a VALID string double into a double Double.parseDouble(result); will turn the string "result' into a double

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer a bit?

Comment: if you ever have a string => in this case "result" was set to a string on line 3. 
The key "test" in the myJSONString variable has a value of 100.00

In order to "DOUBLEFY" this value of 100.00, you call the parseDouble method from the Double class.  Thats is how to convert a VALID string double into a double 
Double.parseDouble(result); will turn the string "result' into a double