# What is wrong with my JSON string?

Tags: java, json, gson

I think the `JSON` string I had was working fine. I stumbled across on my unit tests and found out that my `JSON` parsing using google `Gson` library doesn't work anymore. Does anybody have any ideas why this is not working?

```
String json = "{\"hybrid\":\"true\",\"trimName\":\"act\"}";
JsonObject data = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
System.out.println(" JSON is  "+data);
System.out.println(" JSON is  "+data.get("hybrid"));
```

The output I get is

```
 JSON is  {}
 is hybrid ?  null
```

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20152710/gson-get-json-value-from-string?rq=1

Comment: json string looks good to me. There is nothing wrong in the json data.

Comment: your code works for me. i get 
JSON is  {"hybrid":"true","trimName":"act"}
JSON is  "true"
There is nothing wrong with json string.

Comment: Maybe a classpath issue? Try to run this with minimal dependencies and see if it works then. Maybe you have a conflicting JsonObject class.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1

Solution in `JsonObject` as well using `JsonParser` to convert JSON string directly into `JsonObject` without using `Gson`.

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) parser.parse(json);

System.out.println(" JSON is  " + jsonObject);
System.out.println(" JSON is  " + jsonObject.get("hybrid"));
```

output:

```
 JSON is  {"hybrid":"true","trimName":"act"}
 JSON is  "true"
```

#### Solution 2

You can convert JSON string into `Map<String, String>` using `TypeToken` and `Type`

```
String json = "{\"hybrid\":\"true\",\"trimName\":\"act\"}";
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, String> data = new Gson().fromJson(json, type);

System.out.println(" JSON is  " + data);
System.out.println(" JSON is  " + data.get("hybrid"));
```

output:

```
 JSON is  {hybrid=true, trimName=act}
 JSON is  true
```