# How to show video url from external database(mysql) in android?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, video

I have a project android app stream video from video url is saved in database. But I dont know how to show video from video url in database? Please, help me.... :)

```
public class PlayerActivity extends Activity {

private stream stream;
private ServerRequest server;
private Object newString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
    stream = new stream();
    server = new ServerRequest();
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras == null) {
            newString= null;
        } else {
            newString= extras.getString("alamat");
        }
    } else {
        newString= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("alamat");
    }
    final VideoView vid = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    Uri video = Uri.parse(server.sendGetRequest(ServerRequest.urlSelectAll+"?id="+stream.getId().toString()));
    vid.setVideoURI(video);
    MediaController hhh = new MediaController(this);
    vid.setMediaController(hhh);
    vid.requestFocus();
    vid.start();

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

I want to play video when I click from list view, this list view from my database where in my database table have 2 coloumn : video name and video url. This my main activity for list view

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private ListView listView;
private ActionMode actionMode;
private ActionMode.Callback amCallback;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private ServerRequest serverRequest;
private List<stream> list;
private ListAdapterStream adapter;
private stream selectedList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    serverRequest = new ServerRequest();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_main);
    list = new ArrayList<stream>();
    /** melakukan load data melalui AsyncTask */
    new MainActivityAsync().execute("load");
}





private List<stream> processResponse(String response){
    List<stream> list = new ArrayList<stream>();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("stream");
        Log.d(TAG, "data lengt: "+jsonArray.length());
        stream str = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            str = new stream();
            str.setId(obj.getInt("id"));
            str.setVideo(obj.getString("video"));
            str.setAlamat(obj.getString("alamat"));
            list.add(str);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    return list;
}

private void populateListView(){
    adapter = new ListAdapterStream(getApplicationContext(), list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int pos, long id) {
            if(actionMode != null){
                return false;
            }
            actionMode = startActionMode(amCallback);
            v.setSelected(true);
            selectedList = (stream) adapter.getItem(pos);
            return true;
        }

    });

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int pos,
                                long id) {
            selectedList = (stream) adapter.getItem(pos);
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayerActivity.class);
            in.putExtra("id", selectedList.getId().toString());
            in.putExtra("alamat", selectedList.getAlamat());
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });



}

private class MainActivityAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("retrieving...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            /** Mengirimkan request ke server dan memproses JSON response */
            String response = serverRequest.sendGetRequest(ServerRequest.urlSelectAll);
            list = processResponse(response);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                populateListView();
            }
        });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an API, with NodeJS or PHP that connects to your MySQL database. [Simple JSON for PHP](https://github.com/AlexisTM/Simple-Json-PHP) would do the trick.

Then, you just have to retrive the url from the returned JSON via the [GSON library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Several other subjects are about the same problem. [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20152710/gson-get-json-value-from-string)