# how to fetch result from json with gson library

Tags: java, android, rest, okhttp

I am fetching result from soundcloud api with okhttp library and gson library but I don't know how to use this properly, can I use Asynctask and gson library or should I use retrofit for this purpose
Here is my code

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
Button b;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View p1)
            {
                // TODO: Implement this method
                MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask();
                task.execute();
            }           
    });
}
 }
```

MyAsyncTask.java

```
 public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,String>
 {

public static final String API_URL = "https://api.soundcloud.com";
public static final String CLIENT_ID ="iZIs9mchVcX5lhVRyQGGAYlNPVldzAoX";
String url = "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=iZIs9mchVcX5lhVRyQGGAYlNPVldzAoX";
String res;
Context ctx;
Track t;
String temp;
List<Track> tracks;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void[] p1)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

    try
    {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        res = response.body().string();     

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        String err = (e.getMessage() == null) ?"Failed to translate": e.getMessage();
        Log.e("failed:", err);  
    }
    return res;
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    //Toast.makeText(ctx,"result "+result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("Track","");
    Log.e("res", result);
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
  }
```

Track.java

```
 public class Track
  {
@SerializedName("title")
private String mTitle;

@SerializedName("stream_url")
private String mStreamUrl;

public String getTitle()
{
    return mTitle;
}

public String getStreamUrl()
{
    return mStreamUrl;
}
 }
```

My json result is in String res value, so how can i display only track title name with gson library?

Comment: You should use Retrofit since it is "ridiculously" fast.

Comment: I tried with that but it throw an error of java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)  for method SCService.getRecentTracks

Comment: I tried to search for this error but not found any solution that's why i did this code

Comment: Please post your full logcat and your build.gradle file.

Comment: I referred this tutorial and same steps i followed but app crashed at showing Toast with songs name https://www.sitepoint.com/develop-music-streaming-android-app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20152710/gson-get-json-value-from-string).

Format the string to Gson format and then retrieve your title.

```
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
res = response.body().string(); 
Track[] track = new Gson().fromJson(res,Track[].class);
```

track[] now contains a list of tracks, to retrieve each track you need to iterate through the list and retrieve each track title. E.g., `track[0].getTitle()` should return your first song.

I did a quick example in python to see if it works (don't have my Java environment on this PC).

Here is the code in **Python**

```
import urllib, json
url = "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=iZIs9mchVcX5lhVRyQGGAYlNPVldzAoX"

response = urllib.urlopen(url)
array = json.loads(response.read())

for index, value in enumerate(array):
    print array[index]['title']
```

And here is my output:

```
"What Kind Of" by Maïmouna Guerresi
Swiftness - Akrown Mix
Disney Network Is So Corruped
Closer - The Chainsmokers (Cover)
VISUALISATION OF SOUND. S.Letov, R.Stolyar, A.Vostrtikov, G.Averin.
s a d  m a n  h o u r s
Jackass Alt76 MasteringBOX
OBEDIAH-SERIOUS - TIMES. GAP STOPPING RIDDIM TIMES
idrk
Ghost (OG COVER)
Stadtratswahlen 2018: Stefan Erdös ist ein Wahlbeobachter
Hoi Han Trong Anh -  Ben Heineken  Remix
XXXTentacion - Changes Remix By Joseph Okuwa
NCT_DREAM_엔시티_드림_GO
新曲0305
How Can Love Be Mature - demo
【ハッピーガバコンピ】トリフィドの友人(cribbing ver)
20170322
10 toes challenge Rip Ari2x and Quasean (12/12/2017)
Note
Miniature Authority (short logo music)
Linnahalli Kai
Jacquees- 10-4 (Chimpmunk Version)
Stars
Madrid (King Richard Cover)
Systemaudio - Part 1
Londonvybes.com 2018 Update On Grenfell
Brink Remix [Ray Punch]
Validation on the road
i'll kill it when im asleep
The forever land
Avicii – How Many Lovers(Drop)/ MODE COLD BREW JINGLE
Imperial 1 - Papa Did You Know (Audio)
Dj Devil School Armenia Freestyle Remix ريمكس ديجي دفل اسكول فرستايل.MP3
album nyckelharpa solo - part 1
Strips(ep.1)
We'll Get By
Are We Too Hard on Rookies? - The Left Turn
Bluddy Katon (OG COVER)
The 1960s Were Great
Where is the love?
```

Comment: Got this error FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-04 15:03:46.387 28899 28924 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: com.sk.scdownloader, PID: 28899
03-04 15:03:46.387 28899 28924 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Comment: Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
03-04 15:03:46.387 28899 28924 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)

Comment: Can do do a system.out.print on 
response.body().string();
So I can see the format of the response string?

Comment: Have u tried this code? I don't know what's going wrong here, and which method should I use if i want to fetch multiple objects in ArrayList?

Comment: Why my code is not working is since the link : https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=iZIs9mchVcX5lhVRyQGGAYlNPVldzAoX - does not only return 1 song, it returns an array of tracks. Try creating an array Track[] track = new Gson().fromJson(res,Track[].class);

Comment: Code worked but it returned json array and I want only song name

Comment: Of course it returns an array, to get song title you need to iterate through the array and get each song name. E.g. = track[0].getTitle() should return the title for first song in the array.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro i really apparite your help :)